# How could I customize context menu item click callback?

Tags: android, contextmenu

In my case, I have a `ListView` which contains two kinds of views, folders and images. When long press on a folder, a `ContextMenu` with 2 items "Enter the folder" and "Bookmark the folder" shows up, and when for images, a `ContextMenu` with "View" and "Delete" shows up.

Generally, I should just override `onContextItemSelected` in `Activity` and list all possible menu item IDs in a switch-case. But actions on folders and actions on images are two completely unrelated things, right? Is that strange to put those two (or even more) things in one function?

I wonder, is there a way that I could set callback handlers to each context menu instead of messing up `onContextItemSelected`? Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Are you using a custom ListAdapter? Is it possible to put a context menu listener in there? I'm suggesting this as a comment because I haven't done it before, but that would be the first thing I consider.

Comment: @aha sorry but `ListAdapter` doesn't seem to support that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think using ContextMenu is neither flexible nor convenient decision at all.

Yes, it is strange to process 10 or more *different* actions in one method, so maybe it's better use AlertDialogs instead of ContextMenu. Look at this:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AddingAList

Looks like context menu, right? You can show dialog in your element's OnLongClickListener or in AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener (in case of ListView), and you can process actions in DialogInterface.OnClickListener.

Also look at the question I asked, perhaps it will be helpful for you too: [How to create dialog that looks exactly like ContextMenu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6958622/how-to-create-dialog-that-looks-exactly-like-contextmenu)

Answer (score 0):

In your `onCreateContextMenu()`-method, you can determine if a folder or an image was clicked by checking the passed `View`-parameter.

After that, you could create a separate menu for your folders and one for your images (a different XML-file for every menu) and inflate it.

In the `onContextItemSelected()`-method, you then simply check for all of the possible entry's (no madder which menu got loaded). Since you only have four different possible menu-items, this will not be too bad.

Comment: That is what I've done. And in the real project there are more than 10 entries like "email it", "upload to picasa", etc.  T_T