# How to create dialog that looks exactly like ContextMenu?

Tags: android, android-layout, dialog, contextmenu

Sometimes it`s not convenient to use standart activity methods for creating ContextMenu (because there is can be many places in one activity but in different classes where it would be necessary to show contextmenu).

But creating dialogs is easy from any place.
How can I create dialog that looks exactly like ContextMenu? Where can I find layout of standart context menu or something like that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I decide to use `AlertDialog`s with list (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AddingAList) instead of `ContextMenu`. It looks like ContextMenu (perhaps, not exactly, because of different layouts), but it's more flexible, cause I can handle different actions in different listeners.

Answer (score 1):

You can find `MenuBuilder`, `ContextMenuBuilder` and `MenuDialogHelper` useful (see [code here](http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch#cZwlSNS7aEw/frameworks/base/core/java/com/android/internal/view/menu/&type=cs)). In particular, `MenuDialogHelper` is the closest thing to what you are trying to achieve.

Pay attention to next menu type:

```
/**
 * The menu type that represents a menu dialog. Examples are context and sub
 * menus. This menu type will not have a corresponding MenuView, but it will
 * have an ItemView.
 */
public static final int TYPE_DIALOG = 2;
```

Combined with this lines:

```
// Order must be the same order as the TYPE_*
static final int ITEM_LAYOUT_RES_FOR_TYPE[] = new int[] {
    com.android.internal.R.layout.icon_menu_item_layout,
    com.android.internal.R.layout.list_menu_item_layout,
    com.android.internal.R.layout.list_menu_item_layout,
};
```

Its clear that `list_menu_item_layout` is the layout you are looking for. It can be found [here](http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch#cZwlSNS7aEw/frameworks/base/core/res/res/layout/list_menu_item_layout.xml&exact_package=android&q=list_menu_item_layout&type=cs). This layout represent single item in context menu list view.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! But it is not public api (is it?) and I can only copy this layout and hope that its system copy won`t be changed later, right?

Comment: So maybe it`s good idea not to use context menus at all and to show standart dialogs instead of it. It will be more flexible decision.

Comment: Yes, you're right. They are private and if any of the Android vendors customize the look of context menu, your app will look different. But if you only want to make those menus consistent across your own application activities, then yes - use only your custom dialogs instead of context menus in all cases.